# TSQL Check if date of work completion is less than today

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime, datediff

In a employee task application i have to find if the employee has finished the task on time or he is working overtime so i put together this to find it's not working

```
SELECT case when (CAST('2011-1-1' as datetime) < cast('2011-1-2' as datetime)) THEN 'Finished' ELSE 'UnFinished' end
```

well the dates are hardcoded here because i wanted to test the logic first before going on.

#### Edit

Sorry i missed the select before the select statement hence the error

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'`.

But now i want to know if there are more efficient ways to do above taking into account that compared fields are **datetime**

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need TODAY and date of work finished is datetime, then better use this expression:

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME 
SET @today = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112)

SELECT 
  case when WorkFinishedAt_Column < @today THEN 'Finished' ELSE 'UnFinished' end
FROM YourTable
```

**OR**

if you have only one value in variable

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME
SET @today = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112)

SELECT 
  case when @WorkFinishedAt < @today THEN 'Finished' ELSE 'UnFinished' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use IF ?
if (CAST('2011-1-1' as datetime) < cast('2011-1-2' as datetime))
 select 'Finished' 
ELSE  select 'UnFinished'